# ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object --Laravel unit test

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-6.2, laravel-unit-test

Recently I am working on a project 'facebook-clone' using Laravel and vue.js. I have been using unit test for the first time.
After performing the test I found this error,

Error: "ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"
[image: Error: "ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"]

For sending a friend request I wrote this

test.a_user_can_send_a_friend_request
[image: a_user_can_send_a_friend_request]

I am using many to many relationships in User Model.

many to many relationships within users model

[image: many to many relationships within users model]

this is the pivot table friends [image: friends]

Api route:

api.php

[image: api.php]

The Controller used:

FriendRequestController

[image: FriendRequestController]

The resource used:

Friend [image: Friend]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, I made a mistake in FriendRequestController where I should have passed an argument in Friendesource, instead I passed an array by mistake.

With error:

```
return new FriendResource([
        Friend::where('user_id', auth()->user()
        ->id)->where('friend_id', $data['friend_id'])
        ->first()
    ]);
```

after fixing error:

```
return new FriendResource(
        Friend::where('user_id', auth()->user()
        ->id)->where('friend_id', $data['friend_id'])
        ->first()
    );
```